# VBA Array is being transposed into the second column of a range, not sure why?

Tags: excel, vba

I have the below VBA code which calculates a number of output values and stores them in as an array (beginning_gross_facility_balance being one of the examples).

when I try to print the resulting array values into excel (to output2 range, which is  C16:J515 in an excel tab, the array is exported/printed into column D and from row 17.

currently, i = 1 and j = 25

grateful if someone could shine some light on why this is happening/how can I ensure that the output is copied into the first column and first row of the range

Sub AssetProjection2()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

```
'pluming variables
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

Dim Period As Integer
Dim numberOfLoans As Integer
numberOfLoans = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("LoanCount")) - 1
ReDim tape(numberOfLoans)
Dim pool_lag As Double
Dim total_gross_facility_limit As Double
Dim beginning_gross_facility_balance(500, 500) As Double
Dim interest_rate As Double
Dim arrangement_fee As Double
Dim admin_fee As Double
Dim Audit_fee As Double
Dim insurance_fee As Double
Dim exit_fee As Double
Dim loan_term As Double
Dim loan_remaining_term As Double
Dim default_flag As String
Dim GDV As Double
'only relevant for loans with no seasoning
Dim first_tranche_percentage As Double
Dim seasoning As Double
Dim adjustment_factor As Double
Dim development_fees As Double
Dim lag As Double
Dim sev As Double


'temps/ output variables on a loan by loan basis (so i can call info from any period and any loan)

Dim pmt As Double
Dim Recovery As Double
Dim TempDefault(500, 500) As Double
'end of period balance is the cumulative gross facility at any given point, at maturity, this should match total gross loan limit
Dim end_of_period_gross_balance(500, 500) As Double
Dim periodic_interest(500, 500) As Double
Dim cumulative_retained_interest(500, 500) As Double
Dim periodic_gross_drawdown(500, 500) As Double
Dim periodic_net_advance(500, 500) As Double
Dim cumulative_net_advance(500, 500) As Double
'the loan redeems in one go, then principal and interest redemptions are split for transparency
Dim total_facility_repayment(500, 500) As Double
Dim principal_redemption(500, 500) As Double
Dim interest_redemption(500, 500) As Double


'pristine/stressed variables
Dim prin As Double
Dim prepay As Double
           
'scenarios
Dim DefScen As Integer
Dim PrepScen As Integer
Dim SevScen As Integer
Dim LagScen As Integer
Dim IRScen As Integer

'ouput variables



'the below is currently not being used
Dim oBegBalance(500) As Double
Dim oEndBalance(500) As Double
Dim oDefault(500) As Double
Dim oInterest(500) As Double
Dim oPrincipal(500) As Double
Dim oPrepayment(500) As Double
Dim oRecovery(500) As Double
Dim oAccrued(500) As Double
Dim oCumTheoreticalDef(500) As Double

'initialise CF time
Period = 1
pool_lag = Range("total_lag").Value

  
'this loop will project asset cashflows assuming non-seasonality, then the next loop will look-up the figures for each loan based on the loan's seasonality

For i = 1 To numberOfLoans
SevScen = Range("severity_scen").Cells(i + 1)
LagScen = Range("lag_scen").Cells(i + 1)
'IR scenario currently not in use, when floating interest is modelled, this will be already plugged in
IRScen = Range("IR_scen").Cells(i + 1)
interest_rate = Range("interest_rate").Cells(i + 1)
loan_remaining_term = Range("loan_remaining_term").Cells(i + 1)
loan_term = Range("loan_term").Cells(i + 1)
seasoning = loan_term - loan_remaining_term
first_tranche_percentage = Range("first_tranche_percentage").Cells(i + 1)
total_gross_facility_limit = Range("total_gross_limit").Cells(i + 1)
adjustment_factor = 1.1
admin_fee = Range("admin_fee").Cells(i + 1)
default_flag = Range("default_flag").Cells(i + 1)
    For j = 1 To loan_term + pool_lag
    lag = Range("LagScenarios").Cells(loan_term + j + 4, LagScen)
    sev = Range("severityScenarios").Cells(loan_term + j + 4, SevScen)
        If j = 1 Then
        arrangement_fee = Range("arrangement_fee").Cells(i + 1)
        Audit_fee = Range("Audit_fee").Cells(i + 1)
        insurance_fee = Range("insurance_fee").Cells(i + 1)
        Else
        arrangement_fee = 0
        Audit_fee = 0
        insurance_fee = 0
        End If
        If j = loan_term Then
            exit_fee = Range("exit_fee").Cells(i + 1)
        Else
            exit_fee = 0
        End If
        development_fees = arrangement_fee + Audit_fee + insurance_fee + admin_fee
        Recovery = 0
        'term is original term, not really used anywhere at the moment, only as a static figure to work out seasonality for input curves
        loan_term = Range("loan_term").Cells(i + 1)
        'remaining term doesnt need to be dynamic as the PMT formula takes the current J into account to work out the dynamic remaining term
        loan_remaining_term = Range("loan_remaining_term").Cells(i + 1)
        interest_rate = Range("interest_rate").Cells(i + 1)
        
        If j = 1 Then
            beginning_gross_facility_balance(i, j) = total_gross_facility_limit * first_tranche_percentage
            Else
            beginning_gross_facility_balance(i, j) = end_of_period_gross_balance(i, j - 1)
        End If
        
        'gross drawdown. if first disbursment, it's first_tranche_percentage, else, it's a fixed figure such that from month 2 to maturity, the total gross facility equals the gross loan limit. for the model, I will start with a basic number and learn how to apploy a goal  seek/solver figure
        'draws happen at the beginning of the period and so every period's accrued interest is on the end of period balance J - 1 + period J further draw (J=1 has end of previous period as 0 bcs the loan is new
        
        If j = 1 Then
            periodic_gross_drawdown(i, j) = 0
            
            Else
                If j < loan_term Then
                
                periodic_gross_drawdown(i, j) = (total_gross_facility_limit - periodic_gross_drawdown(i, 1)) / (loan_term - 2) / adjustment_factor
                
                Else
                
                periodic_gross_drawdown(i, j) = 0
                
                End If
        End If
            
        If j = 1 Then
        periodic_net_advance(i, j) = beginning_gross_facility_balance(i, j) - development_fees
        Else
        periodic_net_advance(i, j) = periodic_gross_drawdown(i, j) - development_fees
        End If
        
        If j = 1 Then
            cumulative_net_advance(i, j) = periodic_net_advance(i, j)
            Else
            cumulative_net_advance(i, j) = cumulative_net_advance(i, j - 1) + periodic_net_advance(i, j)
        End If
        
        
        periodic_interest(i, j) = (beginning_gross_facility_balance(i, j) + periodic_gross_drawdown(i, j)) * interest_rate
        
        
        end_of_period_gross_balance(i, j) = beginning_gross_facility_balance(i, j) + periodic_interest(i, j)
        
        If j = loan_term And default_flag = "N" Then
            
            total_facility_repayment(i, j) = end_of_period_gross_balance(i, j)
            principal_redemption(i, j) = cumulative_net_advance(i, j)
            interest_redemption(i, j) = total_facility_repayment(i, j) - principal_redemption(i, j)
            
        Else
            total_facility_repayment(i, j) = 0
            principal_redemption(i, j) = 0
            interest_redemption(i, j) = 0
        End If
            
        
        If j = loan_term + lag And default_flag = "Y" Then
                Recovery = total_facility_repayment(i, j - lag) * (1 - sev) 'accrue some defaulted int rate or keep it simple?
            Else
                Recovery = 0
            End If
        Next j
        
    Next i
    
            

'write it out
'Range("beginning_balance_output") = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(beginning_gross_facility_balance)
Range("output2") = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(beginning_gross_facility_balance)
' Range("output2").Columns(3) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(periodic_net_advance)
'Range("output2").Columns(4) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(cumulative_net_advance)
' Range("output2").Columns(5) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(total_facility_repayment)(end_of_period_gross_balance)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you don't declare the lower bound of the arrays. Per default, VBA set the lower bound to 0, but you don't use the 0th row and/or column in your code.

If you write `Dim TempDefault(500, 500) As Double`, the `500` is used as upper bound, giving you an array of 501 x 501 (from 0 to 500) elements.

You can do the following:

**(a)** Declare the arrays like this:

```
Dim TempDefault(1 to 500, 1 to 500) As Double
```

**(b)** Rewrite your code to that it deals with the 0-row and column of the array

**(c)** Put the following statement at the top of the module:

```
Option Base 1
```

That will force the compiler to use 1 as lower bound if omitted at the declaration.

I would advice to use the first option and **always** declare the lower and upper bounds.